# Stiffness of members in a bolted joint

Tags: mechanical-engineering, bolting, stiffness

I'm trying to calculate the safety factor against separation of members in a design that looks like this:

[image]

I know how to find the bolt and cylinder stiffness, but I don't know how to find the stiffness of the effective loaded area of the plates. I'm used to calculate the stiffness of hollow cones as represented here:

[image]

but this is not the case. Any suggestions?